# Filter Java List by two unique attributes

Tags: java, arraylist, sortedlist

Please I'm trying to filter a list which I queried from the DB by  two unique attributes. Here is a sample of the table:

```
id | seatNo | time | type
=== ======== ====== =====
1  |   1    |   1  |  1  *
2  |   2    |   1  |  1
3  |   1    |   2  |  1  *
4  |   2    |   2  |  1
5  |   3    |   1  |  2  *
6  |   4    |   1  |  2
```

The lines with asterisk(*) are the unique values for both time and type. How do i write a loop that filters this list for unique objects by both the time and type. I have tried something like this:

```
int currentTime = 0;
int currentType = 0;
List<Bus> sortedBuses = new ArrayList<>();
for (Bus bus : allSeats) {
    if (bus.getTime()!= currentTime && bus.getType != currentType) {
        sortedBuses.add(bus);
    }
    currentId = bus.getTime();
    currentType = bus.getType();
}
```

But this doesn't filter properly. I can only get unique values like where time & type are equal. Any ideas that could help me solve this are welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to filter against the busses which are stored in `sortedBuses`

```
List<Bus> sortedBuses = new ArrayList<Bus>();

outerloop:
for (Bus bus : allSeats) {
   for (Bus sorted : sortedBuses)
      if (bus.getTime()==sorted.getTime() && bus.getType == sorted.getType)
        continue outerloop;
   sortedBuses.add(bus);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to filter by unique `time` and `type` field, I've introduced a string which can be read as

```
<time>_<type>
```

Then it is now more easier to find the unique elements:

```
List<String> foundTimeType = new ArrayList<String>(); // represents a list of known types
List<Bus> sortedBuses = new ArrayList<>();
for (Bus bus : allSeats) {
    String timeType = "" + bus.getTime() + "_" + bus.getType();
    // only add if timeType is not present in foundTimeType list
    if (! foundTimeType.contains(timeType)) {
        foundTimeType.add(timeType); // to keep it unique
        sortedBuses.add(bus);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know , maybe is not what you are looking for , but instead of ArrayList you can use **HashSet** , in java this data structure doesn't insert duplicate by default . Of course this mechanism is working only for primitive types , for a custom objects(as your) you should override hashcode and equals methods to make the mechanism work .

Here an example with your case :

```
public class Bus {

    private int type;

    private int time;

    public Bus(int type, int time) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
            this.type = type;
            this.time = time;
    }

    public int getType() {
        return type;
    }

    public void setType(int type) {
        this.type = type;
    }

    public int getTime() {
        return time;
    }

    public void setTime(int time) {
        this.time = time;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        final int prime = 31;
        int result = 1;
        result = prime * result + time;
        result = prime * result + type;
        return result;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Bus other = (Bus) obj;
        if (time != other.time)
            return false;
        if (type != other.type)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And your main will be :

```
import java.util.HashSet;


public class Main {

    public Main() {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        HashSet<Bus> buses = new HashSet<Bus>();
        Bus b1 = new Bus(1, 1);
        Bus b2 = new Bus(1, 1);
        Bus b3 = new Bus(2, 1);
        Bus b4 = new Bus(2, 1);
        buses.add(b1);
        buses.add(b2);
        buses.add(b3);
        buses.add(b4);

        System.out.println("size: "+buses.size());
 for(Bus bus : buses) {
            System.out.println(bus.getTime()+" "+bus.getType());
            }


    }

}
```

Output:

```
size: 2
1 1
1 2
```

In addition , if your object (Bus) implements Comparable , it means you will override the method `compareTo(Object o)` , instead of HashSet you can use **TreeSet** and you will get even sort data structure.

Comment: Thanks for the input, and this solution would cause a lot of refactor and I dont really have that time to check it out

Answer (score 0):

This could be solved in one line using the stream API, by collecting the time and type into the key of a map and then simply exporting the values. The key would contain the time and type.

The line would be:

```
buses.stream().collect(toMap(b -> String.format("%d_%d", b.getType(), b.getTime()), p -> p, (p, q) -> p))
                    .values();
```

Here are a simple test:

```
List<Bus> buses = Arrays.asList(new Bus(1, 1, 1), new Bus(2, 1, 1),
                new Bus(3, 2, 1), new Bus(4, 2, 1),
                new Bus(5, 1, 2), new Bus(6, 1, 2));
Collection<Bus> res = buses.stream().collect(toMap(b -> String.format("%d_%d", b.getType(), b.getTime()), p -> p, (p, q) -> p))
                .values();
res.forEach(System.out::println);
```

This prints out on the console:

```
> Bus{id=1, type=1, time=1}
> Bus{id=5, type=1, time=2}
> Bus{id=3, type=2, time=1}
```

Comment: Hi, This is cool but I can try this if you include the toMap(Obj, Obj, Obj) function. I haven't really gotten a hang of the advanced Stream API functions

Comment: Just add this import statement: *import static java.util.stream.Collectors.toMap;*